# Slim .htaccess with HTTPS/SSL

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, slim

**Background**

I have a Slim-based API inside a sub-directory of my main website app.  For legacy reasons we are not branching them (the web application and the api) into separate virtual hosts or document roots.  Also, for legacy reasons, the website application is NOT Slim-based.

In the top level of the website application we are using a .htaccess file that is redirecting every request over SSL.  This is working fine and dandy for any requests not directed to our Slim API.

**The Problem**

However, this rewrite rule is not applying to the API.  I do have a Slim-based .htaccess I retrieved from the Slim Framework site itself.  If I send a request to http I get a response instead of a 404 or 500.  I need my API to be secure and only respond to HTTPS--just like the rest of the parent site.

**The Question**

Anyone know how I can either: 1) inherit the top-level .htaccess rewrite rules and prevent access to the API over HTTP or, 2) work with the Slim-based .htaccess and secure my Slim-based API over SSL--while still preserving routes and avoiding Slim 404 errors?

Comment: Redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS is only mainly useful for browser usage, when users type the wrong thing in the address bar, and only works if there's no MITM (see [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628)). If the clients that talk to your API don't know they should use HTTPS URI, you have a more fundamental problem. The URLs they are configured with should use `https://` and subsequent links/addresses they get should also be given using `https://`. HTTP->HTTPS redirections will not solve your problem unfortunately, they'll just give you the illusion they do.

Comment: Although I had found a solution to do the above, I had come to a similar conclusion when thinking about it a little more--that the API consumers should know to use https and if they don't...then like you said, there is a more fundamental problem.